# Match fixed string + numbers 0-10 with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a list of files such as this:

```
Sample_lane1-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob2_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob4_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob5_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob7_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob3_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob4_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob6_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob7_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob11_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob12_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob13_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob15_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob16_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob18_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob19_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob20_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob11_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob12_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob16_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob17_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob19_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob20_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane8-Sample1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane8-Sample2_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane8-Sample3_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane8-Sample4_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane8-Sample5_R1.fastq.gz
```

I want to return only the files that are labeled 'Bob1' through 'Bob10' in order to perform some downstream actions, and I want to return the files labeled 'Bob11' through 'Bob20' similarly.

I have been trying to use `grep` for this with a regular expression, but have not been able to match both 'Bob' and the adjacent numeric range. For example, this is one of the many lines that have not worked:

```
grep -E "Bob@([10|0-9])"
```

I have tried many different combinations of `Bob`, `10|0-9`, `"`, `()`, and `[]` in different places based on different tutorials I have found online but none have worked so far.

EDIT: For completeness, this solution given by @anubhava solved the above question:

```
grep -E "Bob(10|[0-9])_"
```

I did not specifically ask for the regex to return the other half of the range, 'Bob11'-'Bob20', but came up with this solution for it as per [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) page:

```
grep -E "Bob([1-2][1-9])_"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex for `grep` against a file:

```
grep -E "Bob(10|[0-9])_" file
```

However if you are using `glob` pattern in a directory then use this `extended glob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
printf "%s\n" *Bob@(10|[[:digit:]])_*
```

**Output:**

```
Sample_lane1-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob2_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob4_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob5_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob7_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob1_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob3_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob4_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob6_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob7_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This was the solution: `grep -E "Bob(10|[0-9])_"`. Turns out that the trailing '_' made the difference, because otherwise the matches for Bob11 - Bob20 kept also getting returned because '`Bob1`x' and '`Bob2`x' matched the original pattern as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tool that can do math instead of relying on a regexp then you can select any range you like:

```
$ awk -F'-Bob|_' '$3+0>7 && $3+0<13' file       
Sample_lane1-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane1-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob10_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob8_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane2-Bob9_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob11_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane3-Bob12_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob11_R1.fastq.gz
Sample_lane5-Bob12_R1.fastq.gz
```